# Div centers on JSFiddle but not on html page

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, jsfiddle

I've been trying to vertically center some images in my code, and I finally got a solution working on JSFiddle but when I try to paste the same code to a html file the contents aren't centered. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kf8mksy0/ and the images are centered vertically:

[image]

But when I try to paste the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0; 
                width: 100% !important;
                font-size: 100%;

                -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;

                background-color: #FAFAFA
            }
            #header {
                background-color: #FFF;
                height: 53px;
                padding: 19px 0;
                border-top: 6px solid #000; 
                border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
                min-width: 450px;
                margin: auto;
            }
            #header-content-left {
                float: left;
                padding: 0 0 0 5%;
                height: 53px;   
            }
            #header-content-center-1{
                float: right;
                height: 53px;
                line-height: 53px;
                padding: 0 2% 0 2%;
                border-left: 1px solid #000;
                margin: auto;
            }
            #header-content-center-2{
                float: right;
                height: 53px;
                line-height: 53px;
                padding: 0 2% 0 1%;
                margin: auto;
            }
            #header-content-right {
                float: right;
                height: 53px;
                padding: 0 5% 0 2%;
                border-left: 1px solid #000;    
            }
            #header-content-center-1 img, #header-content-center-2 img {
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: middle;

                line-height: normal;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">

                <div id="header-content-left"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/50/" width="175" height="53"/></div>

                <div id="header-content-right"><img src=            "http://lorempixel.com/150/50/" width="96" height="52" /></div>

                <div id="header-content-center-1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/50/" width="78" height="12" /></div>
              <div id="header-content-center-2"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/50/" width="76" height="12" /></div>

                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

The small buttons aren't centered vertically anymore:
[image]

I have tried the same code in Chrome, Firefox and IE so I'm sure it's not just browser-wide. Am I missing some declaration? I have `DOCTYPE`, `xlmns` and `meta` tag declarations on my final html but it is not working there either.

Comment: On your JSFiddle,  I don't see the images as centred? https://jsfiddle.net/kf8mksy0/embedded/result/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSfiddle uses html5 declaration.
You can change this from the fiddle options on the left. 
I used this code in a simple html page and works fine in chrome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 100% !important;
                font-size: 100%;
                -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
                background-color: #FAFAFA
            }
            #header {
                background-color: #FFF;
                height: 53px;
                padding: 19px 0;
                border-top: 6px solid #000;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
                min-width: 450px;
                margin: auto;
            }
            #header-content-left {
                float: left;
                padding: 0 0 0 5%;
                height: 53px;
            }
            #header-content-center-1 {
                float: right;
                height: 53px;
                line-height: 53px;
                padding: 0 2% 0 2%;
                border-left: 1px solid #000;
                margin: auto;
            }
            #header-content-center-2 {
                float: right;
                height: 53px;
                line-height: 53px;
                padding: 0 2% 0 1%;
                margin: auto;
            }
            #header-content-right {
                float: right;
                height: 53px;
                padding: 0 5% 0 2%;
                border-left: 1px solid #000;
            }
            #header-content-center-1 img, #header-content-center-2 img {
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: middle;
                line-height: normal;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="header-content-left">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/50/" width="175" height="53" />
            </div>
            <div id="header-content-right">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/50/" width="96" height="52" />
            </div>
            <div id="header-content-center-1">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/50/" width="78" height="12" />
            </div>
            <div id="header-content-center-2">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/50/" width="76" height="12" />
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**UPDATE:**

> How "DOCTYPE" affects the rendering of HTML elements on different browsers?
>
> Different browsers render the different tags differently. Whenever we define a DOCTYPE, it means we are telling to the browser that HTML Standards of the specified DOCTYPE have been used.

[Doctype info](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/792524/DOCTYPE-Explored)

Comment: Huh, that's odd! `<!DOCTYPE html>` works but  `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` (dreamwaver default, I think) does not.

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard HTML5 doctype.  That seemed to do the trick across the IDEs/browsers I have installed, but I'm not sure why 4.01/etc..doesn't work.

EDIT:  Ah bollocks, idioteque found it...nice catch buddy!

- List item